# SQL Server Management Studio Schema View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

I'm working with a SQL server and several databases. Each database may have many schema's, such as dbo., admin., other., and I'm getting tired of scrolling around trying to find things.

If I'm working on a schema specific project, I want to filter out everything else from my view except that schema. As dbo, I see everything which means I spend the majority of my day molesting my scroll wheel (that is a joke).

Is this possible in SQL Server Management Studio 2008?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In SSMS 2005 or 2008, right click on the heading: "Stored Procedures", "Tables", etc, then on "Filter Settings", then for the "Schema" change "Operator" to "Does not contain" or "Contains", etc and then set a Value to filter them...

Comment: Awesome! I never knew about the filter. The only filter that works is "Creation Date". Name, Schema, and Owner don't let me apply a filter. Perhaps a bug. Regardless, +1 for the filter!

Comment: Ok this is funny. I have to paste the value into the filter. Typing into the filter does nothing.

Comment: +1, but... any way to do this so all objects are filtered instead of just a subset?  Some SSMS addin perhaps?  While this filter is better than nothing, I'd love to be able to have a "schemas" folder under the database tree node that further contains tables/views/procs per schema.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: don't connect as db_owner or "sa".

Connect as a user that can access and change the desired schema only.

This way, the engine "[Metadata visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113.aspx)" will do it automatically

Comment: Can I do it without changing who I connect as?

Comment: @Coov: If you change your rights. The engine returns objects you're allowed to see... so whether a different user or different rights acheives the same result

Answer (score 0):

FYI, I was searching for tables under cdc schema, the change data capture schema that was created. After much struggle, I found that those tables are in the Tables->System Tables folder. So SSMS did show the non default schema but in this case it was in a different folder.

Comment: To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.