# SSMS object explorer sorting order?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I created the following schemas and hope their objects be shown at the bottom of object tree. However, they are on the top instead. Is there any special characters that be shown in the bottom in SSMS explorer tree?

```
create schema [~temp]
create schema [{temp}]
```

Comment: I always use zzzzz     .....

Comment: Shouldn't your schema name be something to give it some relevance instead of the placement in a list?

Comment: @SeanLange I want a schema name for these objects need to temporarily keep for a while before deleting. That's why I want it sink to the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking for a character that sorts after `z`?

Take your pick from any of these

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT TOP 65536 NCHAR(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)) AS C
FROM master..spt_values v1, 
     master..spt_values v2
)
SELECT *
FROM T 
WHERE C > 'Z'
ORDER BY C
```

For example

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Ξtemp]
```

or

```
CREATE SCHEMA [Жtemp]
```

would both work though not be convenient to type

[image]

Comment: You might need to use a lower case z depending on the collation of your database.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe you can.

What you could do though is filter it out completely; from

[SQL Server Management Studio Schema View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337164/sql-server-management-studio-schema-view)

`In SSMS 2005 or 2008, right click on the heading: "Stored Procedures", "Tables", etc, then on "Filter Settings", then for the "Schema" change "Operator" to "Does not contain" or "Contains", etc and then set a Value to filter them...`

I've just checked and it is still applicable in SSMS 2014

You would need to remember that is is there, though. Calendar reminder?

EDIT:

Ah, I miss-read the question. I was looking at other methods of ordering the list. I'll leave my answer here as an option, but I acknowledge it wasn't what you asked for.